# Unable to use most of the methods of samsung-tv-control package, getting error -RangeError: Invalid WebSocket frame: invalid status code 1005

Tags: node.js, ip, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-tv

Want to access my Samsung Smart TV (Tizen OS) using the IP protocol, for that using **samsung-tv-control package** [npm package link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/samsung-tv-control?activeTab=readme)
, I am unable to use most of the methods, in the below code I am unable to get the token and unable to get the installed applications information. Also not sure what must be the token value in the config variable.

**Error ->** RangeError: Invalid WebSocket frame: invalid status code 1005

**Here is my node.js code** -

```
const express = require("express");
const { Samsung } = require("samsung-tv-control");
const app = express();

let isAvailable = false;
const config = {
  debug: true, // Default: false
  ip: "xxx.xx.xxx.xxx",
  mac: "xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx",
  nameApp: "NodeJS", // Default: NodeJS
  port: 8001, // Default: 8002,
  noServer: true,
  token: "", // token value (but not sure what to put here, what must be the token value ?)
};

const control = new Samsung(config);

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  res.send("TV control" + JSON.stringify(control));
    try {
      control.turnOn();
      isAvailable = await control.isAvailable();
      console.log("isAvailable: ", isAvailable); // getting true
      if (isAvailable) {
        //getting error on using this code
        control.getToken((token) => {   
          console.info("# Response getToken:", token);
        });
        //getting error on using this code
        control.getAppsFromTV((err, res) => {
            if (!err) {
              console.log("# Response getAppsFromTV", res);
            }
          });
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log("Server running successfully on 3000");
});
```

Here the screenshots of the errors -
[Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzbrN.png)

[Error Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BS174.png)

I Want to access my Samsung Smart TV (Tizen OS) using the IP protocol to get the Installed apps on the TV and to launch them as per the request.

Answer (score 0):

tv-control uses remote control to port 8001, but Tizen TV blocks access to port 8001, which is a non-secure port.

Comment: I have tried with port 8002 also, but no luck same error

Comment: What do you mean by "non-secure port"?

Comment: what is the token in this case, and how to get it ?

Comment: did you manage to solve this issue?